# Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord query using a join. Find fields whose number of associations is not more than the limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have servers in different regions. Several servers in Germany, Holland, Sweden... Configurations are stored on servers. For clarity, in my case, vpn settings. Each server has a limit on the number of configurations (500 configurations on average, so as not to overload the server). I need to find a non-crowded server in a certain region. For example, a user wants to create a configuration on a German server. **I need to find all servers where the number of configurations does not exceed the server limit and take the first one.**

```
class Region < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :servers
end

class Server < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :configs
  belongs_to :region
end

class Config < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :server
end
```

i tried this:

```
Server.joins(:region).joins(:configs).where(region: {name: "Germany"}).group('servers.id').having('COUNT(configs.server_id) < servers.available_count_of_configs').first
```

*I expect that this will return me the first server that belongs to the region of germany and in which the number of configurations is less than available_count_of_addresses*
Thanks

Comment: I think the issue here is that `HAVING` operates on the group as a whole. Not per row. You would have to use an aggregate function like `MAX(servers.available_count_of_configs)` or something like a subquery or a lateral join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's about subquery? You can get configs count for each server and compare it with available count

```rb
Server.
  joins(:region).
  where(regions: { name: 'Germany' }).
  where('available_count_of_configs > (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM configs WHERE server_id = servers.id)').
  order('servers.id').
  first
```

It's unclear what do you mean about "first one", in this query order by server id is used

Comment: It's not that important, just for an example, that I expect to get any available server. Of course, I can filter differently and take the busiest one from the set. I am grateful to you, your answer is correct. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

regions should be plural in your `where` clause:

```
Server.joins(:region, :configs)
      .where(regions: { name: "Germany" })
      .group('servers.id')
      .having('COUNT(configs.server_id) < servers.available_count_of_configs')
      .first
```